# In Webpack HRM, how to watch onky part of code?

Tags: webpack

I'm using Hot Replace Mode in my development everyday. But as project grows larger and larger, the performance is becoming working.

In my project there are 2 entries:

- `vendor`: libraries like React, lodash, moment
- `main`: my project code

React is quite large codebase, I think that may cut down the CPU occupation a lot by leaving them alone. Is there any chance that I precompile `vendor` before I start `webpack-dev-server --hot`, and make it watch code in `main` only?

Answer (score 0):

You can improve performance a lot by defining a `include`. Example:

```
{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
  include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'main')
}
```

Now it will process only files within your `main` directory as was your intention originally.

There are a lot of smaller tweaks you can do but I think this will give you the most bang for the buck with the least effort.